# Library for cross platform datatypes in C

Tags: c, cross-platform

Is there a C (not C++, Boost etc.) library for providing cross platform datatypes ?

To elaborate, I want to store an `int` in a file in a 32-bit linux machine, read the file and the same `int` from a 64-bit windows machine. Is this possible ?

Update: I do not want to use sqlite or some kind of database either. I want a library which can help me in using the data types throughout my code.

Comment: You need to pick your poison first - ASN.1, xml, whatever - and then find a library that supports it.

Comment: You probably want a serialization library. XDR exist since many years. There are many other alternatives.

Comment: This is about portable binary serialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is store 32 bits signed integers, just decide on a format, for example big endian. You can then write the serialisation/deserialisation yourself:

```
void write_int32_be (int32_t i, FILE *f)
{
  uint8_t buf[4];

  buf[0] = ((uint32_t)i >> 24);
  buf[1] = ((uint32_t)i >> 16) & 0xFF;
  buf[2] = ((uint32_t)i >> 8) & 0xFF;
  buf[3] = (uint32_t)i & 0xFF;
  fwrite (buf, 4, 1, f);
}

int32_t read_int32_be (FILE *f)
{
  uint8_t buf[4];

  fread (buf, 4, 1, f);

  return ((uint32_t)buf[0] << 24) |
         ((uint32_t)buf[1] << 16) |
         ((uint32_t)buf[2] << 8) |
          (uint32_t)buf[3];
}
```

If you need a variety of types, use a library like [tpl](http://tpl.sourceforge.net/), [Eet](http://www.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=about/efl/eet&l=en), [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/), [protobuf-c](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/) or an implementation of a standard like [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), or [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One). If you have large numerical data sets use something like [HDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) or [NetCDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF).

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler(s) know about C99 standard then you can just use **int32_t**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed_width_integer_types
IMHO your OS should have the same endianness. Windows and Linux on x86 and x86_64 are both little-endian, so it should work.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_and_operating_systems_on_architectures

Comment: Note that computation with these fixed width types might be slower than with 'native types' for the architecture. So if speed is your priority you might consider using them for reading and writing to a file only, while in the actual code cast them to int_fast32_t.

Comment: The fixed width types *will* be native types, otherwise they will be missing.